# CardInputWidget is not animating when wrong details are entered

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stripe-payments

CardInputWidget is not [animating](https://stripe.com/img/docs/mobile/android/android-card-input-widget.mp4) when wrong details are entered. It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/com/stripe/android/view/CardInputWidget.html) site that it handles animation on its own.

At least if I could get the error message, I could show in an alert box if not for the animation.

I couldn't find answers. Please help with the issue.

This is my code

```
    private fun loadPage() {

    binding.payButton.setOnClickListener {

        val card = binding.cardInputWidget.paymentMethodCard
        val nameText = binding.nameInput.text.toString()

        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if (nameText.isEmpty()) {
            Utilities.alertBoxSingleBtn(this, "Please fill the name field")
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            return@setOnClickListener
        }

        val billingDetails = PaymentMethod.BillingDetails.Builder()
                .setName(nameText)
                .build()
        if (card != null) { // Create SetupIntent confirm parameters with the above
            binding.payButton.isEnabled = false
            val paymentMethodParams = PaymentMethodCreateParams.create(card, billingDetails)
            val confirmParams = ConfirmSetupIntentParams.create(paymentMethodParams, clientSecretKey!!)
            stripe.confirmSetupIntent(this, confirmParams)
        } else {

            binding.payButton.isEnabled = true
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

This is my widget code

```
<com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
        android:id="@+id/cardInputWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/payButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameInput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameInput" />
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit on what you are expecting from the animation itself? 
Also, what you could do is to use the CardWidget validate callback when user is entering card number while they are typing to show an error message  `card_input_widget.setCardValidCallback(CardValidCallback)`.

Comment: @wsw In this link (https://stripe.com/img/docs/mobile/android/android-card-input-widget.mp4), can you see the card number turning into red when you enter wrong the wrong number. That's not happening in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was replicated in Stripe android version 13.1.2. The bug was fixed in [13.2.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/pull/2114).